# BASH -gt unary operator expected error

Tags: macos, bash, shell, osx-yosemite

I've used the following script successfully on previous versions of OSX to alert me when a disk volume reaches a defined threshold.

When running on Yosemite, it isn't working:

```
% bash disk-full-alert.sh 
disk: 10766513
df: 10766513: No such file or directory
output:
current:
threshold: 65
_________________

disk-full-alert.sh: line 26: [: -gt: unary operator expected
disk: 129154082
df: 129154082: No such file or directory
output:
current:
threshold: 65
_________________

disk-full-alert.sh: line 26: [: -gt: unary operator expected
disk: 710743471
df: 710743471: No such file or directory
output:
current:
threshold: 65
_________________

disk-full-alert.sh: line 26: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH
HOSTNAME='server.example.com'
ERECIP='dan@example.com'
# Threshold is percentage full
THRESHOLD=65


get_data() {
  df -l | grep -v Mounted| awk ' { print $6 } '
}

get_data | while IFS= read -r disk
do
echo disk: $disk
OUTPUT=($(LC_ALL=C df -P ${disk}))
echo output: $OUTPUT
CURRENT=$(echo ${OUTPUT[11]} | sed 's/%//')
echo current:  $CURRENT
echo threshold: $THRESHOLD
echo _________________
echo " "
[ $CURRENT -gt $THRESHOLD ] &&
 (
echo "From: Server Admin <admin@$HOSTNAME>"
echo "To: $ERECIP"
echo "Subject: Warning!! $disk file system is $CURRENT% full on $HOSTNAME"
echo ""
date
echo ""
echo "ALERT!!"
echo " "
echo The $disk file system is $CURRENT% full
echo

) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -it
```

Ideas or suggestions most appreciated!

Dan

Comment: Please follow [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You've made a good start, but "isn't working" doesn't qualify as an error description.

Comment: try [indenting your code](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39210/whats-the-standard-for-indentation-in-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly the output of `df` has changed, rendering your script incorrect. It looks like column 6, which is intended to be the `mount point`, has somehow become one of the metrics (`blocks`, `available`, `used` and so on).

You'll need to run `df -l` to check that column 6 is still the right one for what you need. If not, fix the script or find a way to run `df` in "legacy" mode so it reverts to the old format.

Comment: you were correct, it was column 9 that I needed! Thanks for your help. I'll mark this as answered in a minute. Cheers!

Comment: Rats, now the following is giving me fresh error: CURRENT=$(echo ${OUTPUT[12]} | sed 's/%//') and I don't understand this nomenclature...ideas?

Comment: @Dan, that's simply meant to remove the `%` from the end of the percent-used field. Examine the output of `df -P` and, if needed, ask *another* question with full information (similar to this one (which was very well done, by the way), including script and output of script and output of both `df -k` and `df -P`). That's the way SO works and will guarantee a larger set of eyes helping you out.